# XSLT - dynamic node name

Tags: xslt-3.0

I want to convert all child node as attribute name to  Nodes. and attribute value should be the node value.

How do i give dynamic node name?

`<xsl:attribute name="shouldBeNodeName">`

SOURCE XML

```
<transaction>
    <transactionId>T001</transactionId>
    <clientId>C001</clientId>
    <contractId>C001</contractId>
    <scriptId>REL</scriptId>
    <price>500.5000</price>
    <tradeDate>2019-02-09 16:00:00</tradeDate>
    <valueDate>2019-02-09 16:00:00</valueDate>
    <quantity>100000</quantity>
</transaction>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ROOT>
            <TRANS>
                <xsl:for-each select="node()/*">
                        <xsl:attribute name="shouldBeNodeName">
                            <!-- <xsl:value-of select="name()" /> -->   
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </TRANS>
        </ROOT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ROOT>
        <TRANS>
            <xsl:for-each select="node()/*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </TRANS>
    </ROOT>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Note that in XSLT 2 or 3 you can shorten `<xsl:attribute select="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>` to `<xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="."/>`.

Comment: Thanks but did not work, where can i learn about xslt 2/3 with example?

Comment: I had to use different transformer from java.
Replaced `//TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();`
with `TransformerFactory factory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();` and added required maven dependency Thanks !

Comment: There are several books on XSLT and XPath 2 at least, one is available online at https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm, I am sure your favourite bookstore has more. There are also online tutorials like https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3.